Woocommerce Cannot set billing phone to "required"
I have been trying to make the billing phone number a required component, but have been unable to affect it in any way. Here's what I have tried so far
using hooks in functions.php
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'no_billing_phone_validation' );
function no_billing_phone_validation( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing_phone']['required'] = true;
    return $fields;
}

Setting the phone to required in my theme

and using the plugin "Checkout Field Editor for WooCommerce" to set the phone to required

but despite all of this, the billing phone is still optional, and I am able to check out without adding a phone number. Is there anything that I'm missing?


This is because you are using Checkout Block, that doesn't allow making changes like before. You are limited to the available options from those sub-blocks when editing the checkout page via the backend. You can switch to classic checkout as explained here, to be able of customizing checkout as you like.

This seems like it may work, but also gives a totally different checkout page. I'm hoping that I can keep the checkout page that I have

I modified code in file wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/client/blocks/checkout-frontend.js by changing
"showPhoneField":{"type":"boolean","default":true},"requirePhoneField":{"type":"boolean","default":true},

and
showPhoneField: 1,requireCompanyField: !1,requirePhoneField: 1,

Now it works as expected!


Wow I never could have guessed this. Thanks so much!
So if I understand correctly, these seem to be some rules that override all of the other methods I had been using to set this field to required.

In the end i was able to find a solution. The following file defines the object for the billing field woocommerce/src/blocks/domains/services/checkoutfields.php. That file had the following object
        'phone'      => array(
            'label'          => __( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ),
            'optionalLabel'  => __(
                'Phone (optional)',
                'woocommerce'
            ),
            'required'       => true,
            'hidden'         => false,
            'type'           => 'tel',
            'autocomplete'   => 'tel',
            'autocapitalize' => 'characters',
            'index'          => 100,
        ),

Confusingly, if I set required to true, this did NOT actually make the field required. There must be some function overriding that elsewhere. So what I did was delete the phone object and make an identical phone2 object. This was able to be set to required
